# Unit testing with and without private Accessor

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Are there any disadvantages in using a private accessor to test a piece of code?

I'm weighing the option of using a private accessor only to test my GUI, as opposed the the methods/properties that are publically exposed.

This will allow some GUI testing i need, i just wanted to make sure their were not any hidden "pitfalls" in using a private accessor in how it behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to recap, your stated goal is:

> > I'm weighing the option of using a private accessor only to test my GUI...  This will allow some GUI testing i need...

In short, yes there are pitfalls.  The code you are testing is still tightly coupled to the user interface.

In the comments you clarify your goal/problem as:

> > What about in the case if i want to test, Drag/drop. Custom Controls, Overriden events?

All I can say is welcome aboard.  The software industry has struggled with this for nearly half a century.  The fact remains that testing UI is hard, Really HARD.  Yes you can take a piece of code that is tightly coupled with a UI element and try and automate it; however, your going to be fighting tooth-and-nail to make headway against poor assumptions.

The 'trick' to testable UI is not to make your UI testable, but to remove the code you want to test from the UI.  Thus the wide acceptance of N-Tier application development and presentation design patterns like MVC, MVVM, etc.

see the following:

- [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
- [Model View ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)
- [Model–view–adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93adapter)
- [Model–view–presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

The primary goal or driving force behind many of these design patterns is to remove the tight coupling between behavior and presentation.  This enables you to then test a behavior like drag-n-drop without a user interface.  My recommendation is review the patterns, choose one you like, and then start refactoring the code as you write your unit tests.

Another way to think of writing UI for testing is to remove every if, else, for, while, switch, or other [control statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) from your user interface code.  The resulting 'shell' of a UI should be very resilient to change.  Just be careful when using things like data binding that rely on reflection (which is generally an acceptable practice).  The primary downside to this is that the compiler can not tell you that a member no longer exists.

**Updated**

@timmy you wrote:

> > ... for example if i want to test mouse click behavior...

So what about the mouse click behavior cannot be moved to a controller rather than being embedded into the form?  I guess the "Close" button might have a problem, but beyond that why not move the logic to another class that can then be tested?

BTW, You don't have to pick just one pattern MVC, MVVM, etc, they are 'guidelines' or 'suggestions' not hard rules so don't get ridiculous with it.  Just try and make the logic separate from the UI and independently testable.  As an example, perhaps your "Click" event fits better with a simple command class?  Using a command pattern  is easy, new up an object and execute it.  Consider this example code for a folder copy form:

```
private void OnCopyClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var cmd = new MyCopyCommand(this.FolderPath, this.txtTargetFolderPath.Text);
    new ErrorHandler(this).Perform(cmd);
}
```

This works well, it has no 'real' logic other than what to provide the command and has no conditional code paths.  Notice we don't even directly invoke the command but rather defer that to someone who can handle an error appropriately.  Usually this 'ErrorHandler' would be provided to the Form rather than constructed directly, but you get the idea.

From this we should be easily able to verify the correct behavior of the MyCopyCommand.  In the end you should wind up with a bunch of "flat functions" in the UI, ie. functions that have no nesting or curly braces.  Of course this is a rule of thumb, not to be taken to such an extreme as to prevent you from being productive.

I know this may seem like a lot of work, but truthfully it is not when you are already working to write a set of tests.  You can be productive *AND* write solid code.  You just need to know when to cheat, and when not to.  That comes with experience and after 20 years, 10 of those writing NUnits, I still fail once in a while.  When something breaks because you didn't do this, first extract the logic from the UI, then write a unit test to prove it's broken, then fix it.

Comment: Thanks csharp, this helps alot, one more question. Say its not possible to refactor all our logic out of our view. And i want to test our user stories through UI tests. Such as, Given-Window in default state, when ButtonX is pressed, Then text turns green. And i can test all of this through the UI directly, do you see anything wrong with that? Or is it not really testing the UI?, such as performClick()..or if i used a private accessor and setup event calls myself.

Comment: @timmy I guess my point is that if your going to all the trouble to write unit tests, why not refactor the code you are testing using an appropriate design pattern.  IMHO this is going to produce a set of tests that are more stable and less error-prone than doing the kind of 'reach-around' you are suggesting.  I admit this may slow down the initial test development, but in the end you get better code both in the production code as well as the unit tests.  Seems like an easy decision to me, fewer tests but a higher quality code base.

Comment: Yea, i can see your point about refactoring and i agree probally our code could follow design patterns better. It just seems to me that even with MVC/MVP there will  be code in the View layer that cannot be hit, and why not write a test for it if possible? About the private accessor though, for example if i want to test mouse click behavior over certain elements, and i can. Would it not be benifitial to test the View even if i pushed as much down as possible? I guess i just have difficultly with saying mock out the view and test only the layers below the view.

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to use them, instead try to find out if you can inject any dependency. Unless you're working on a legacy code where you want to create some unit tests using private accessors, I'd suggest not to use them and even in this case, I'd recommend you do that temporarily until you refactor legacy code.

Comment: What about in the case if i want to test, Drag/drop. Custom Controls, Overriden events? The problem we have is our View Breaks alot, and the layers below the view won't catch the errors. I'm trying to build a test class to cover these cases. As well as cover ATTs.

Comment: It depends on your architecture, in MVVM or MVP you can trigger the event and test your code handling the events but it won't test the real view itself. So if you want to test view you should have UI tests.

Comment: Why won't it test the real events? If you can fire events, and after the events, all your view data is in the correct state. Isn't that like a UI test?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what AD.NET said.
I could use those private properties in tests only until I finish my refactoring (to Model View Controller, Model View Presenter, Model View ViewModel) so that I don't have to test GUI at all!